# Найти кол-во элементов, заканчивающихся на 9

Tags: c, бинарное-дерево, дерево

Есть задание: найти количество элементов в дереве, которые заканчиваются на 9. (9, 19, 29 и т.п.).
И, собственно, проблема в том, что я не могу придумать как это сделать. Находила поиск элемента через `count()`, но в случае с деревом оно не работает (ну или же проблема в моем не понимании)

Код:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <time.h>       
#include <iomanip>  
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
struct bintree
{
    int inf;            
    bintree* left;      
    bintree* right;     
};
bintree* proot = NULL;
void RemoveBinaryTree(bintree** proot)
{
    if (*proot != NULL)
    {
        RemoveBinaryTree(&((*proot)->left));
        RemoveBinaryTree(&((*proot)->right));
        delete* proot;
        *proot = NULL;
    }
}
bintree* CreateNode(const int pinf)
{
    bintree* node = new bintree;
    node->inf = pinf;
    node->left = node->right = NULL;

    return node;
}
bool IsUniqueValueInsert(bintree* proot, const int pinf)
{
    // "прошли" все дерево, не встретив дубликатного значения
    if (proot == NULL)
        return true;

    // встали на узел, имеющий такой же ключ (встретили дубликат)
    if (pinf == proot->inf)
        return false;

    // продвигаемся по дереву
    if (pinf < proot->inf)
        return IsUniqueValueInsert(proot->left, pinf);
    else
        return IsUniqueValueInsert(proot->right, pinf);
}
void Insert(bintree** proot, const int pinf)
{
    if (*proot == NULL)
        *proot = CreateNode(pinf);
    else
        if (pinf < (*proot)->inf)
            Insert(&((*proot)->left), pinf);
        else
            Insert(&((*proot)->right), pinf);

}
int irand(const int pa, const int pb)
{
    return (rand() % (pb - pa + 1) + pa);
}
void MakeBinaryTree(bintree** proot, const int pn)
{
    if (*proot != NULL)
        RemoveBinaryTree(proot);
srand((time)=NULL);
    for (int i = 1; i <= pn; i++)
    {
        int key = irand(0, 100);
        while (IsUniqueValueInsert(*proot, key) == false)
            key = irand(0, 100);
        Insert(proot, key);
    }
}
void LKP(bintree* proot)
{
    if (proot != NULL)
    {
        LKP(proot->left);
        cout << setw(8) << proot->inf;
        LKP(proot->right);
    }
}
/*bool SearchNodeByKey(bintree* proot, const int pkey)
{
    if (proot == NULL)
        return false;

    if (proot->inf == pkey)
        return true;

    if (pkey < proot->inf)
        return (SearchNodeByKey(proot->left, pkey));
    else
        return (SearchNodeByKey(proot->right, pkey));
}*/
void postorder(bintree* proot, int indent)
{
    if (proot != NULL) {
        if (proot->right) {
            postorder(proot->right, indent + 4);
        }
        if (indent) {
            cout << setw(indent) << ' ';
        }
        if (proot->right) cout << " /\n" << setw(indent) << ' ';
        cout << proot->inf << "\n ";
        if (proot->left) {
            cout << setw(indent) << ' ' << " \\\n";
            postorder(proot->left, indent + 4);
        }
    }
}
void parnielementy(bintree*& proot) {
    bintree* Left, * Current, * Right;
    int Lefbintree, Righbintree;
    Current = proot;
    if (Current->right == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Only one element in list" << endl;
        return;
    }
    while (Current != NULL) {
        Left = Current->left;
        Right = Current->right;
        Lefbintree = 0;
        Righbintree = 0;
        while (Left != NULL) {
            if (Left->inf % 2 == 0) {
                Lefbintree++;
            }
            Left = Left->left;
        }
        while (Right != NULL) {
            if (Right->inf % 2 == 0) {
                Righbintree++;
            }
            Right = Right->right;
        }
        if (Lefbintree == Righbintree) {
            cout << "Element: " << Current->inf << " has same amount of elements on the left (" << Lefbintree << ") and on the right(" << Righbintree << ") " << endl;
        }
        
    
    }
}
void findnine(bintree*& proot) {//конец прикола
    int num = 9;
    //count(proot->inf, 9);
}
int main()
{
    cout << "======================================================" << endl;
    cout << " Choose oprion below: " << endl;
    cout << "1. Create tree" << endl;
    cout << "2. Show tree." << endl;
    cout << "3. Add to tree" << endl;
    cout << "4. Show all elements in tree, which ends with 9" << endl;
    cout << "5. Find elements, amount of paired elements in right are equal to left." << endl;
    cout << "6. Delete tree" << endl;
    cout << "======================================================" << endl;
    int key, n;
    while (true) {
        cout << "\nChoose option: ";
        cin >> key;
        switch (key) {
        case 1: {cout << "Enter amount of elements in Tree: ";
            cin >> n;
            MakeBinaryTree(&proot, n); } break;
        case 2: {cout << "Symetrical: " << endl;
            LKP(proot);
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Postorder: " << endl;
            postorder(proot, 0); } break;
        case 3: {int a;
            cout << "Enter element you wanna add: ";
            cin >> a;
            Insert(&proot, a); LKP(proot); } break;
        case 4: {findnine(proot); }break;
        case 5: {parnielementy(proot); }break;
        case 6: {RemoveBinaryTree(&proot); }break;
        }
    }
    if (proot != NULL)
        RemoveBinaryTree(&proot);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: рекурсивно : запустить слева, справа и посмотреть ещё у себя в корне. вернуть сумму.

Comment: @AlexGlebe а можно подробнее? Сумму чего нужно вернуть? И как это поможет найти элементы с 9 на конце..

Comment: [Сумма всего] = [Сумма в левой ветке] + [Сумма в правой ветке] + [Если число в данном узле заканчивается на 9 ? 1 : 0]